# Azure Mobile Service DateTime Deserialization at Android Error

Tags: android, json, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Service and call the post table service.

Record is created and return the object but I got the "Invalid length" json deserialization error as follow. May I know how to solve this issue.

```js
02-10 00:45:31.613    2975-2981/com.takemetomyanmar.myanmarticket E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
02-10 00:46:11.553    2975-2975/com.takemetomyanmar.myanmarticket E/AMS﹕ Exception
    com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Invalid length
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.DateSerializer.deserialize(DateSerializer.java:84)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.DateSerializer.deserialize(DateSerializer.java:54)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.DateSerializer.deserialize(DateSerializer.java:1)
            at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:859)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:832)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.JsonEntityParser.parseResults(JsonEntityParser.java:62)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceTable.parseResults(MobileServiceTable.java:307)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceTable.access$13(MobileServiceTable.java:305)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceTable$ParseResultOperationCallback.onCompleted(MobileServiceTable.java:93)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceJsonTable$2.onCompleted(MobileServiceJsonTable.java:249)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceJsonTable$4.onPostExecute(MobileServiceJsonTable.java:389)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceJsonTable$4.onPostExecute(MobileServiceJsonTable.java:1)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you check the date time value in the debugger or by using a print statement?